# gitlab merge request by command line

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, pull-request

I am working with gitlab.

First of all, i did not find "Pull Request" feature on gitlab. I suppose this is named "Merge Request" ?

Here is what i want to understand:

Let's suppose we have a project called project1. This project is a public gitlab project, written by user1.

Now, let's suppose we have a contributor (user2), who wants to change something on project1.
Here are the steps user2 should do:

1. Fork project1, in gitlab web interface (Fork button)
2. Clone the forked project on his local computer.
3. create a branch (brtest)
4. Write or change source code files
5. commit changes
6. push brtest into the forked project
7. On gitlab web interface, ask for a merge request

User1 will see a new merge request opened in his gitlab web interface. Let's suppose user1 agree with the changes made by user2.

If user1 clicks on "Merge" button, i can see a link which explains me which CLI commands i should type. This is where i want to understand something.

Here are the commands:

```
git fetch git@gitlabserverofuser2/user2/project1.git brtest
git checkout -b localbrtest FETCH_HEAD
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff localbrtest
git push origin master
```

I have understood FETCH_HEAD represents what is fetched on the first line. My first question is what should i type instead of FETCH_HEAD ? I have tried to type this but it does not work:

```
 git checkout -b localbrtest git@gitlabserverofuser2/user2/project1.git/brtest
```

I have also typed

```
git branch
git branch -a
git branch -r
```

I do not see anything about remote brtest branch. I know it will work with FETCH_HEAD keyword. But, in order to understand, i want to know the "value" of FETCH_HEAD.

Next question, why do they put a no fast forward paramter. Is it dangerous to omit this parameter and what is the risk ?

Last question: The merge does not show me conflicts. It erase and replace files.
In some case when i am working with local branches on a single project, i can sometimes see files which contains a diff when there is a conflict. Why does git not apply the same behaviour in case of merge request ?

Thanks

Comment: `FETCH_HEAD` is a built-in git alias for a commit.

Comment: Thanks but how can i "read" its value ?

Comment: Use `git show`.

Comment: no it does not give me the value

Answer (score 0):

FETCH_HEAD is a pointer to the top of your git history. The most recent state.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you'll only get a conflict if two branches have modified the same file in the same place.  It's a conflict because `git` doesn't know which change you actually want.  If you haven't made any changes that conflict, git will tell you and then you'll need to use a merging program to choose the changes you want to keep.

You're probably not seeing a conflict because you're working on different parts, and no conflict exists.